# Swift equivalent for (__bridge NSArray*)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift

I am attempting to get a list of contacts with a certain name using swift. I have the following code:

```
let owner = owners[indexPath.row];

var addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil)
var addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(addressBook.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()

let ownerName: NSString = owner["name"]! as NSString

let allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBookRef, ownerName)

println("All Contacts: \(allContacts)")
```

Apparently, `allContacts` has a value of `Swift.Unmanaged`. I would expect `allContacts` to be an `NSArray`.

In the tutorial I'm following `allContacts` is bridged to `NSArray` by adding `(__bridge NSArray*)` to `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBookRef, ownerName)`.

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: You might want to share a link to this tutorial, because generally you would use `(__bridge_transfer NSArray *)` (or `CFBridgingRelease()`), to transfer ownership to ARC. Makes life much easier. If you used `(__bridge NSArray *)`, then you'd have to manually  `CFRelease` the `CFArrayRef`. Anyway, `__bridge` is equivalent to `.takeUnretainedValue()`, and `__bridge_transfer` is equivalent to `.takeRetainedValue()`. FYI, the `fromOpaque`/`toOpaque` dance is no longer needed anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're doing a lot more wrapping/unwrapping `Unmanaged` and `Opaque` types than necessary. Your line:

   ```
   var addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(addressBook.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
   var addressBookRef = addressBook.takeUnretainedValue()
   ```

   (And besides, you should be using `let` unless you want to assign another value to that variable, which seems unlikely. The optimizer will thank you.)
2. You shouldn't need to cast to Foundation types when passing parameters to AddressBook APIs, either... but I can't make `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName` return a non-empty array in my testing, even with ObjC, so it's hard to say.
3. If you just want to print the array, you need nothing more than this (using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` instead because of the above issue, but usage of the returned array is the same):

   ```
   let addressBook: ABAddressBook = 
       ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
   let allContacts =
       ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()
   println("All Contacts: \(allContacts)")
   ```

   (Presumably sometime between getting the `addressBook` and using it you're either checking `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()` or calling `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`, right?)
4. If you want to work with the `ABRecord` values in the array, you'll need to do a bit of casting. CoreFoundation types bridged to Foundation types, and Foundation arrays are bridged to Swift arrays, but it doesn't bridge all the way from CF to Swift automagically.

   ```
   for contact in ((allContacts as NSArray) as [ABRecord]) {
       let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contact).takeRetainedValue()
       println(name)
   }
   ```

   (I put parentheses in that `for` statement to show the hierarchy of operations, but you don't actually need them in your code.)

Comment: You have to use `takeRetainedValue()` here, because the "Copy" functions return a +1 retained value.

Comment: Good catch. I blame bad copy-pasting from my test project. 

Comment: ... that applies to ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions() as well.